# EclipseLinkを使ったマルチテナントの実現方法

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss

Wildfly10で、EclipseLinkを使っています。
アプリケーションを利用するテナントごとにDBを分けたいです。
（目的は負荷分散です。データの保護はDBの行レベルセキュリティを使います）

調べてみると、正しくこれ、といった記事が見つかりました。

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/06/15/jakarta-ee-multitenancy-with-jpa-on-wildfly-part-1#implementation_code

`MultiTenantConnectionProvider`インタフェースを実装することにより、`Connection`インスタンスを自分で制御できるので、私にとって完璧なソリューションです。
しかしこれは、Hibernateを使った記事でした。

EclipseLinkに同等の機能はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

Wildflyで管理区分を分けたくない理由って何でしょう。
通常、テナント分けるってことは、セッション数の管理やDBコネクションプールの監理なんかも分けるはずで、その場合はDBコネクションのレイヤではなく、EJBサーバ内での、管理区分を分けるほうが自然な気がします。

なぜ、DB接続レイヤだけでの切り分けなのか素朴な疑問として教えていただきたいです。
すいません。直接の回答ではりませんが。。

以上

Comment: `管理区分`とはなんでしょうか？